# Segmentation Fault if I don't say int i=0

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, initialization, int

```
void removeVowels(char* array){
  int i,j,v;
  i=0;

  char vowel[]={'a','e','i','o','u'};
  while(array[i]!='\0')
  {
    for(v=0;v<5;v++)
    {
      if (array[i]==vowel[v])
      {
          j=i;
          while(array[j]!='\0')
          {
            array[j]=array[j+1];
            j++;
          }
          i--;
          break;
      }
    }
    i++;
  }


}
```

in function `removeVowels()` if I don't include `i=0`; and just say `int i;` why does it give segmentation fault? Isn't it automatically `0`?

Full code [here](http://pastebin.com/eHkbm5ev)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `int i` is an automatic local variable. If not initialized explicitly, the value held by that variable in indeterministic.

So, without explicit initialization,  using (reading the value of ) `i` in any form, like `array[i]` invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), the side-effect being a segmentation fault.

> *Isn't it automatically 0?*

No, variables with *static* storage class will get this "facility" of implicit initialization, not automatic local variables.

Answer (score 5):

> Isn't it automatically 0?

No, it isn't. It `i` has automatic storage, so its default initialization leaves it uninitialized, holding an indeterminate value. To read from it before initializing it is *undefined behaviour*.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare `int` globally then it is initiated with the value `0`. Otherwise it contains garbage value. You can try the following code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int global;

int main()
{
    int local;
    printf("global = %d, local = %d\n", global, local);
    return 0;
}
```